# How to check the content of the wwwroot folder of the Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function app that is deployed on Azure.
I am debugging some issue with the app,so I need to check the content of the wwwroot folder to understand the root cause of problem. I have been reading all the documents,but I couldn't find it.
How I can check the content of the wwwroot folder while app is running. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are related questions and answers.
Simple way is by using Advanced Tool (Kudu Services) from the azure portal.

1. Sign-in to portal.azure.com
2. Select your Azure Function App
3. Select Advanced Tools in the side bar and select 'Go'.
4. This will dislplay the Kudu Services.
5. Select Debug console | CMD
6. Select site | wwwroot folder to check the content of the folder.

Comment: thanks for the instructions that helped.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Snekithan's answer:

The shortcut to get to Kudu for both an App Service and a Function App is `[app-name].scm.azurewebsites.net`.

If you would like to use something that looks a lot like an online VS Code editor, go to `[app-name].scm.azurewebsites.net/dev` on any Windows hosted App Service or Function App.

[image: App Service Editor]